# Calculating the points of a football team by knowing their wins/matches in C

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok, I am doing a C++ online challenge where I have to calculate the points a team has by knowing their matches (win, lose, equal etc).

A program input is the following:

```
3
4 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 4
```

I have to output the points of the team with highest amount of points.

In this case 4x3=12 is the highest, so the output should be 12.

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[150],b[150],c[150];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i] >> b[i] >> c[i];
    }

    sort(a,a+n);
    sort(b,b+n);
    sort(c,c+n);

    int temp;

    if(a[0]>b[0])
    {
        temp=a[0];
        a[0]=b[0];
        b[0]=temp;
    }
    if(b[0]>c[0])
    {
        temp=b[0];
        b[0]=c[0];
        c[0]=temp;
    }
    if(c[0]>a[0])
    {
        temp=c[0];
        c[0]=a[0];
        a[0]=temp;
    }
    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << b[0] << endl;
    cout << c[0] << endl;
    cout << a[0]*3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know it looks bad.. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Where's the 3 coming from?  The only one i see appears to be nothing more than a count of lines.

Comment: Actually...why not just link the problem?  There's obviously some info here we haven't been given.

Comment: What do you mean where's the 3 coming from? What 3 are you talking about?

Anyway, the problem is full here, I can't link as it's foreign language (not English). But if that helps, the input order is (win|equal|lose), win gets you 3 points, equal is 1 point and lose is 0 points.

Comment: *That* 3.  :)  See, it helps a bit when you provide the information that matters.

Comment: Well, considering how popular football is nowadays, I considered everyone to know how many points a win gets you. My mistake though, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: This is an English-speaking site in the US.  We call football "soccer" ("football" is a whole other game), and it's not nearly as big here as it is in the rest of the world.  So, yeah, dunno how it's scored.  :)

Comment: It's alright, as I said it was my mistake for not mentioning that. Not only because of that, but it's programming and Internet, which means the points per win can be changed. So, yea, any help? :)

Comment: Truth is, if i understand your intentions, you shouldn't be sorting, swapping, etc.  You've just broken any association between line number and score, and between column number and meaning (whether it's a win, loss or draw).  If you want to sort, group the W/L/D into structs and sort those.  But really, just calculate the score, keep track of the max score, and update whenever you have a score that's higher.  If you just want the max score, that's all you need.  The rest is for if you want, say, the top 5 or the stats of the winner, etc.

Comment: Frankly, you don't need any arrays.  At startup, the highest score is -1.  You calculate the points for the incoming row; if it is higher than the current highest (and it will be for the first record, even if they lost every game), then you record the new highest score.  At the end, print out the score.  Arguably, you don't need the 3 on its own in the data set; C can detect EOF.  However, you probably need to pay attention; a sadistic judge might add a record '1000, 1000, 0' just after the last record according to the count (where those 4000 points will be more than any other team has).

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a struct that holds wins ties and losses.
This would allow you to define an `operator<`

Right now you are sorting the wins ties and losses individually which means the data is not staying together.

```
struct TeamInfo
{
    int mWins;
    int mTies;
    int mLosses;  //don't actually use this value but makes it easier to read

    //declare the operator< between two TeamInfo structs
    bool operator<(const TeamInfo & other);
};

//This function allows us to compare two TeamInfo structs.
bool TeamInfo::operator<(const TeamInfo & other)
{
    int myValue = mWins * 3 + mTies * 1;
    int otherValue = other.mWins * 2 + other.mTies * 1;
    return myValue < otherValue;
}

//an example:
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    TeamInfo teamA;
    TeamInfo teamB;

    teamA.mWins = 3;
    teamA.mTies = 2;
    teamA.mLosses = 0;

    teamB.mWins = 0;
    teamB.mTies = 2;
    teamB.mLosses = 3;

    //the < here is the same as going teamA.operator<(teamB);
    //which will return false because teamA is better than teamB
    bool teamAIsBetter = teamA < teamB;

    //sort uses operator< so you could put these structs into an array and call sort

    return 0;
}
```

You can then call sort on these structs.

Comment: The answer is pretty simple, because I don't know structs. Beside, you have to save the equals too, because they bring you 1 point.

Comment: Weird solution, I don't really understand what are you doing.. do you mind commenting the source?

Answer (score -1):

For every team, calculate match_wins * 3 + draw * 1, and find the highest one is fine. I think it is unnecessary to sort the array. 
Part of the code may look like this:

```
int highest_score = -1;
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++ i){
    if( a[i] * 3 + c[i] > highest_score ){
        highest_score = a[i] * 3 + c[i] ;
    }
}
cout << highest_score << endl;
```

Also the output should just be the highest score right? while it seems that you output 4 values.